# How do I make requests to /wp-json/wp/v2/users/me after logging in? (401 error)

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, wordpress-rest-api, jwt

I am trying to create a login using [jwt-auth](https://github.com/Tmeister/wp-api-jwt-auth) to my Wordpress installation in my React site on localhost.

The login itself works fine, my React Site can recognise when username and password are correct and even returns a valid token.

However when I try to make a request to access my user information I get a 401 error.

At this point I have googled this in any way I can think of. I don't even know what I could be doing wrong because the `wp-api` docs tell me to do exactly what I am doing.

Here's my login script:

```
    let message = '';
    this.setState({ message });
    const { username, password } = this.state;
    console.log("trying to log in " + username);
    axios
      .post(`${Config.apiUrl}/jwt-auth/v1/token`, {
        username,
        password,
      })
      .then(res => {
        const { data } = res;
        localStorage.setItem(Config.AUTH_TOKEN, data.token);
        localStorage.setItem(Config.USERNAME, data.user_nicename);
        Router.push('/');
      })
      .catch(() => {
        message =
          ' -  Sorry, that username and password combination is not valid.';
        this.setState({ message });
      });
```

Once I receive the token I make a request for the user info like so:

```
        const token = localStorage.getItem(Config.AUTH_TOKEN);
        console.log(token);
        if (token) {
          wp.setHeaders('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
          wp.users()
            .me()
            .then(data => {
              const { id } = data;
              this.setState({ id });
              console.log(id);
            })
            .catch(err => {
              if (err.data.status === 403) {
                tokenExpired();
              }
            });
        }
```

Just like explained [here](http://wp-api.org/node-wpapi/customizing-http-request-behavior/#set-headers-globally).

But all that I receive back is a 401 error.

If I try running:

```
curl --user user:password creativiii.com/praisethemachine/wp-json/wp/v2/users/me
```

I get the correct JSON response containing my user's information, so the problem has to be with my code and not with the setup.

Question:

- Did I do something wrong while setting up the `define('JWT_AUTH_SECRET_KEY', 'your-top-secret-key');`? I took one of the keys generated [here](https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/) and used that, but maybe that was not what I was supposed to do?

I have also tried using different keys, but that didn't change much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem.

Either I forgot to edit or my .htaccess got reset at some point and I was missing:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

My site is now working fine.

[This guide](https://firxworx.com/blog/wordpress/using-the-wordpress-rest-api-with-jwt-authentication/) helped me a lot, it's a lot clearer than the Git for JWT-auth.